# is it possible to read group feed by using facebook group api? (after 4 april chage)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible after the changes of 4 April, to use Facebook group API in order to read the feed?

Until 4 April i did it via Graph API EXPLORER by using GET request like:
`v2.12/{Group-id}/feed`

using user access token.

This is not working for me anymore.

The service is no longer available or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

> Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process
>   should resume in a few weeks, but apps currently accessing Events and
>   Groups APIs will lose access today.

The feed will just not return some fields anymore, you can read more about it in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#groups-4-4