# Autoposting to Facebook groups, error from Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've faced with problem a week ago

Details:

1. Have already created a many years ago Application (just for posting)
2. Through this app I've send request to Graph Api, POST  /GroupID/feed
3. Problem appeared on 11th of April, but **this affected only groups**, for example the same app using for posting to another open pages and my profile - without any problem
4. Application have enough rights - manage_pages and etc, i've tested many many time with Graph API Explorer and every time the same error for my groups, but for pages - no problem

Response from GraphAPI

```
Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'GroupID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
```

I am the owner of all groups and pages and account with admin rights

Is any restriction from Facebook? I could not find any information about it

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#groups-4-4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965493/is-it-possible-to-read-group-feed-by-using-facebook-group-api-after-4-april-ch/49966814#49966814

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has temporarily suspended all parts of the Graph API that deal with groups. It's supposed to return in coming weeks, but all apps using it will be required to re-apply for the `user_groups` permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

> As we begin enhancing our new app review process and make changes to our platform, the Events, Groups, Pages and Instagram APIs will no longer be available to new developers. Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process should resume in a few weeks, **but apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today**. Going forward, access to these APIs will require a formal app review and for apps using the Pages API, submission is required within 90 days once app review resumes or access will be removed.